# Does a curve $C \subset X$ that contains a singularity of $X$ pick up extra multiplicities?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a variety over a algebraically closed field, and $C \subset X$ is a curve, that contains a singularity of $x$ of $X$. If $D$ is a Cartierdivisor, whoose support $|D|$ contains $x$, is it true that $D|_C$ vanishes at $x$ with multiplicity $\geq 2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example, let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ be a quadratic cone, let $C \subset X$ be its ruling, and let $D = H \cap X$, where $H \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ is a hyperplane passing through the vertex of the cone and transverse to $C$. Then
$$
D \vert_C = (H \vert_X) \vert_C = H\vert_C
$$
has multiplicity 1.

Comment: True, that is a counterexample. Any clue what happens if the singular locus has codimension 1?

Comment: Doesn't matter, just take $X$ a union of two planes in $\mathbb{P}^3$, a line in one of them, and a hyperplane.